# Is it possible to fix the size of a list in python so that if the list contains more than that it'll throw an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input()) #fixed length
l = input().split()
```

the list that I want should be given as one line input so I dont know how range will help??

Comment: Are you editing the data at all? If not just use a tuple because it is immutable!

Comment: Are you by chance looking for the `maxsplit` argument to `split()`?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length using len() and raise the error.

```
if len(l)>n:
    raise Exception('Please give only {} inputs'.format(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) to determine the size of a list or tuple.

```py
if len(l) > n: # assuming n is the max size 
    print("List too large")
```